# Unknown type name NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlsession, nsurl

In Xcode 8, beta 6 the compiler does not seem to recognize `NSURLSession`

I receive an error with `Unknown type name NSURLSession`

My peer who is using an earlier version of the beta does not receive this error. I looked at the Xcode [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/download/) and could not find anything of it being deprecated.

Was there a change to `NSURLSession` in the latest update? The code base is in Objective-C if that matters. It is also using the `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` (which the compiler also tells me `Cannot find protocol declaration for NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`) and suggests `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate instead.

I am simply declaring it as a variable right now and receiving the error

```
NSURLSession *mainSession;

NSURLSession *downloadSession;
```

Edit: I've narrowed down the problem to running it on a physical iOS 10 device.

The simulator devices work fine when compiling.

The physical device is running the latest iOS 10 beta (with respect to Xcode's beta 6).

Could this potentially just be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The `NSURLSession` is defined in the Foundation header.  This is often included via a pre-compiled header (.pch) in the project, or if not there, than explicitly somewhere, as in:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

or, implicitly, by importing another header that imports it, like `UIKit.h`.

If none of those conditions exist within the scope of the code in question, then the foundation symbols like `NSURLSession` will be unknown by the compiler.

Try the import statement above at the top of the implementation file where the error appears.

Comment: The import statement is defined at the top of the implementation file. The error still persists.